# Converting float to array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a dataset like this:

```
    user_id     record_time         accu      lat           lon
0   1335    2017-02-28 18:11:00     21.581  52.130910   -106.639214
1   1335    2017-02-28 18:17:00     21.205  52.130910   -106.639214
2   1335    2017-02-28 18:22:00     21.998  52.131086   -106.638881
```

I wrote two functions to find the average of "lat" and "lon" by grouping the "record_time". This is the code:

```
dflat = df2.groupby(['record_time'])['lat'].mean()

dflat.head()
```

And here is the result for "lat"(I have the same result for "lon" based on "lon" values):

```
record_time
2017-02-05 23:30:00    52.143500
2017-02-05 23:32:00    52.143500
2017-02-05 23:38:00    52.143500
Name: lat, dtype: float64
```

Now I want to  use these average numbers and convert them to UTM coordinate to create a map with them. I use this function:

```
myProj= Proj(init='epsg:32613')
x1, y1 = myProj(dflon,dflat)
print(x1,y1)
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: input must be an array, list, tuple or scalar
```

How can I convert the result of dflat and dflon to array? Or, can I get the average in a different way that give an array in result?

Comment: Maybe you should use the last column of `dflat`

Comment: Try passing `dflon.values` and `dflat.values`.